# Android fragment overlaid by another fragment still isShown and not onPause

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

In my app I catch `onBackPressed` in the `MainActivity` and send a broadcast to fragments. The receiver in each fragment is switched on or off with

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver);

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    int tab = args.getInt("Tab");
    Log.d(log, String.format("Tab1Fragment %d onPause", tab));

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("de.foo.BackPressed");
    receiver = new MyReceiver();
    getContext().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    int tab = args.getInt("Tab");
    Log.d(log, String.format("Tab1Fragment %d onResume", tab));

}
```

Additionally, in the broadcast receiver I check visibility of the fragment to make sure, only the visible fragment can process the `BackPressed` event:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("de.foo.BackPressed")) {
    if (getView() != null && getView().isShown()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I replace an existing and visible fragment with another, `onPause()` is not called on the replaced fragment. Its broadcast receiver is still enabled. Also the receiver in the new fragment. Both fragments give true for `getView().isShown()`, but that is not true: only the last fragment is visible.

How can I achieve that only the visible fragment reacts?

EDIT: The first fragment is loaded in tab 0 of my tabbar. I get the log "Tab1Fragment 0 onResume" and enable the broadcast receiver.
In this fragment, the user taps on a list entry to show an html page. I do it with the following code:

```
            HTML_Fragment newFragment = new HTML_Fragment();
            newFragment.setArguments(extras);
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content, newFragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
```

The HTML_Fragment starts in the same space now and I see the log "HTMLFragment 0 onResume". Only HTML_Fragment is visible now, but I don't get a log "Tab1Fragment 0 onPause". The broadcast receivers of both fragments are active now. That's my problem.

Comment: Please describe task what you try to handle by receiver, maybe I'll help you with way to do it.

Comment: There are different tasks depending on the kind of fragment. The one which is overlaid has to change the list content. The second has to reactivate the first one in the state it was before the overlay.

Comment: Try to use remove and add.

Answer (score 1):

From the code above, I can just guessing, what the root cause of the issue, but I have an idea:

- Make sure, you ***replace*** old fragment with a new one, not ***adding*** the new one on top of the old one:

  ```
   // to show the root fragment
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                  replace(R.id.container, new FragmentA()).
                  commit();
   ....
   // to show subfragment (i.e. fragment which is replacing the root fragment)
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                  replace(R.id.container, new FragmentB()).addToBackStack(null).
                  commit();
  ```

  In this code-snippet - `onPause()` of `FragmentA` will be called just before `onResume()` of `FragmentB` (and when you click back - `onPause()` of `FragmentB` -> `onResume()` of `FragmentA`).

[`replace()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)) - is the same as calling `remove(Fragment)` for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then `add(int, Fragment, String)` with the same arguments. While [`add()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)) - is just add a fragment to the activity state.

If you just `add()` new fragment (or add both, and then just switch them by `show()`/`hide()`) - some of lifecycle methods would slip away from you.

Let me know, if it helps.

Comment: The first fragment (Tab1Fragment) is placed in tab 0 of my tab bar. It is loaded at app start show me the log "Tab1Fragment 0 onResume".

Comment: As you can see in my edited question, I do what you are suggesting. But Tab1Fragment onPause is not called.

Comment: @thpitsch I.e. you have a root fragment with `ViewPager` with `TabLayout`, each page of the `ViewPager` is a `Fragment`(subfragment of the root one) and once you click on the ListItem - it opens **different** fragment, which replaces the root fragment with the newest one, right?

Comment: No, I not use the ViewPager. In the ViewPager there are always two fragments in neighboring tabs active, even if swiping is disabled. I do use only a FragmentTabHost and initialize each tab with Tab1Fragment. A click on a ListItem can load another list in the ListView or replace Tab1Fragment with another Fragment - in this case HTML_Frgament.
The fact, that I use Tab1Fragment on all four tabs is not the problem. I have testet it with only one tab and only one Tab1Fragment. Still the same: Tab1Fragment is replaced by HTML_Fragment but still alive.

Answer (score 0):

No. onResume  and onPause in Fragment is means the Activity's onResume  and onPause.

You can check this by turning to another Activity and go back.And you will find on Pause is called, then the onResume is called.

You can use Fragment.isVisible() to check whether a fragment is in front.

Try to add remove before replace and keep checking isVisible() in receiver.

```
        HTML_Fragment newFragment = new HTML_Fragment();
        newFragment.setArguments(extras);
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        // you can add a tag when add fragment ,and findByTag() to find the fragment.
        ft.remove(mTab1Fragment);

        ft.replace(R.id.content, newFragment);
        //ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
```

Comment: I've changed this in my broadcast receiver:
if (getView() != null && Tab1Fragment.this.isVisible()) {
   ...
}
but isVisible returns true when Tab1Fragment is replaced by HTML_Fragment. Tab1Fragment is not visible at this time.

Comment: Can you check which fragment is receiving the broadcast?

Comment: Both fragments. First at Tab1Fragment, second at HTML_Fragment.
When I manually disable the receiver at Tab1Fragment, the app acts as desired.

Comment: Try to remove ft.addToBackStack(null); if you needn't it.

Comment: The first fragment is not pushed to the back stack. Now I have removed addToBackStack for the second fragment. It changes nothing on my problem. The broadcast in the first fragment is still received. Why is the first fragment still alive? It is replaced bei the second, not added.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not solved. I have ensured through a system of parameters that only the currently visible fragment processes the broadcast.